# CAMT.053 Parser for Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, core-banking

does anyone happen to know a Java-library capable of parsing CAMT.05x (espacially .053) XML files which are used by European Banks for SEPA transfers?

Google won't really help me here...

Comment: While this question is off topic on SO (because looking for a library is off topic) this question, especially with more details would be a good fit for SoftwareRecommendations.SE http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ You may want to consider moving it there.

Comment: https://www.iso20022.org/sites/default/files/documents/messages/camt/schemas/camt.053.001.08.zip

This is the official XSD for CAMT.053 others can be found on https://www.iso20022.org/payments_messages.page

Answer (score 1):

I could find the XSD for CAMT.053 in 
[here](https://github.com/jasperkrijgsman/dutch-sepa-iso20022/blob/master/src/main/resources/camt.053.001.02.xsd) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/leontestbed/source/browse/trunk/bc2/sample/Schema/camt.053.001.02.xsd?r=238)

If you have the xsd, you should be able to generate classes using XJC and then unmarshal the xml.

or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes, we finally ended up doing this.
I was searching for a more sophisticated parser, as the CAMT XML data structure is massively blown-up an redundant, but apparently, there are no open-source parsers out there.
Thanks anyways!

Comment: Maybe you can upload your work for other's help?

Comment: Will definitely do when its stable, needs some more work though. You can already have a look at the nice domain model, if you like :)
http://i.imgur.com/u8F5xh9.png

Comment: @jvataman, did you progress on this library and stabilize it? Is it open source? Thanks

Comment: There is an official ISO entry https://www.iso20022.org/sites/default/files/documents/messages/camt/schemas/camt.053.001.08.zip

Comment: The ISO entry has moved. It can now be found using search: https://www.iso20022.org/iso-20022-message-definitions?scope%5B0%5D=messages&search=camt.053